# How to use a radial gradient with a border-image

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients, border-image

I am trying to use a border image where the source is a radial gradient. I have seen plenty of examples with images but have seen none with radial gradients.

Full example in [My CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyWrqp)

```
#main {
  width: 200px;
  border: 8px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-image:
      radial-gradient( farthest-corner, #777 50%, #7770 60%)  /* source */
      28 /                    /* slice */
      8px 8px 8px 8px /    /* width */
      4px 4px 4px 4px       /* outset */
      round;                  /* repeat */
}
```

I simply want to surround the box in small circles spaced a few pixels apart preferably using a CSS only solution. Though I am happy to hear other issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with background like this:

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  padding:10px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle at center, #777 60%, transparent 61%) top left/10px 10px repeat-x,
   radial-gradient(circle at center, #777 60%, transparent 61%) bottom left/10px 10px repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">This element is surrounded by a radial-gradient-based border image!</div>
```

If you want all the sides you can do this:

```css
#main {
  width: 200px;
  padding:13px 10px;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(circle at center, #777 60%, transparent 61%) top left/10px 10px repeat-x,
   radial-gradient(circle at center, #777 60%, transparent 61%) bottom left/10px 10px repeat-x,
   radial-gradient(circle at center, #777 60%, transparent 61%) bottom left/10px 10px repeat-y,
   radial-gradient(circle at center, #777 60%, transparent 61%) bottom right/10px 10px repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">This element is surrounded by a radial-gradient-based border image!</div>
```

Comment: That looks good - out of interest is there an option with border-radius?

Comment: @RobPethi you mean what? As I didn't use border here

Comment: Sorry - I appreciate your answer which uses the 'background' css rule - it looks good. Is there a way to do it using the 'border-image' css rule?

Comment: @RobPethi no it's not as simple as that to use gradient with border, you cannot have the same good result as background